# While on feature branch, trying to take uncommitted changes onto main branch led to unresolved index

Tags: git

Using git v2.29.2 on Fedora Linux.

I think my workflow is poor so thought I'd ask how to improve it.  I'll probably clean up the mess by backing up files and hard resetting or something but I'm sure there's a better way of doing what I'm doing.

Let's say I've branched a feature branch `F1` off `main` to develop feature F1.  While working on a feature branch you sometimes want to modify files that have nothing to do with F1 when a sudden change request comes in.  I started such work this morning, while on branch `F1` and still having uncommitted files for F1 outstanding.  So I end up with a bunch of uncommitted files in my workspace, some intended for `F1` and some for `main`.

Normally, to be safe, I would commit the files intended for F1 onto `F1`, then attempt to checkout `main` and commit the files for `main`, then move back.  But I got lazy and tried to achieve it without committing onto `F1` first.

My limited experience of git is that you can `git stash` the current workspace, checkout another branch (any conflicts are avoided when you checkout because you've stashed any files that may have conflicted), then `stash pop` to get the changed files back into your workspace.  You can then add files to the index and commit as required.  I sometimes do then when wanting to rebase a feature branch onto `main`.  This is what I tried to do, unsuccessfully.

What I wanted to do was:

```
<F1> $ git stash save
<F1> $ git checkout main
<main> $ git stash pop
.. now should have all modified files while working on F1 back in my workspace.
.. Touch any conflicts if I've edited a file from main that's actually different,
.. add the files intended for main to the index and commit, then move back to F1 branch ..
<main> $ git commit
<main> $ git stash save
<main> $ git checkout F1
<main> $ git stash pop
.. now have all changed files for F1 back in workspace for futher dev or commit ..
```

What actually happened was:

```
<F1> $ git stash save
<F1> $ git checkout main
<main> $ git stash pop
Auto-merging file/on/main/blah.js
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file/on/main/blah.js deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of file/on/main/blah.js left in tree.
CONFLICT (modify/delete): file/on/f1/thing.xml deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes. Version Stashed changes of file/on/f1/thing.xml left in tree.
The stash entry is kept in case you need it again.
```

Both of these seem confusing. `file/on/main/blah.js` is a core project file, existed for 10 years and would never be deleted.  The second, `file/on/f1/thing.xml` is a new file created for `F1` and not known at all on `main`.  So at this point I slightly panic and try to move back onto `F1` to do a "proper" commit of its changed files before trying to move back onto `main`.

```
<main> $ git stash save
file/on/f1/thing.xml: needs merge
file/on/f1/somethingelse.js: needs merge
```

WTF?  thing.xml was completely new on F1 branch, and somethingelse.js is also new and wasn't mentioned in the previous `stash pop` output.

This is all a mess and as I said, I'll try to clean it up by resetting things.  What is the 'correct' workflow to take a mixture of changes when on a feature branch, to take some of them to commit to the main branch and keep the other changed files for the feature branch intact?

Comment: The very-short answer is that `git stash pop` (or `git stash apply`, really—`pop` means `apply` and then if that works, `drop`, but it didn't work in this case) *is* a merge, and hence anything that can go wrong with a merge, can go wrong with the apply step.

Comment: What I *generally* do is go ahead and commit, either on a new just-created branch or right there on the current branch, before backing up and starting fresh with the intended branch. That means that the commit I made isn't for *direct* use in *any* branch, but because I made a normal commit—not a stash—all the usual Git tools work with the commit.

Comment: I agree @torek, as I said in the post, when planning to rebase or do serious merge-type work I would commit and then use normal git tools.  In this case, because I thought the files created for F1 wouldn't exist on `main`, using the stash tools wouldn't create any merge conflicts (beyond simple ones where I'd modified `main` files, which I could resolve).  The "deleted in Updated upstream and modified in Stashed changes" output really threw me. I know it's my repo and there may be hidden mistakes you can't see. Maybe I'll just live with it :) Manual recovery worked OK so I'm good.